# Android - "Method Call Expected" error when trying to build a singleton SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: java, android, sqlite, singleton, android-sqlite

New programmer here trying to self-learn, apologies for any stupid questions.

I'm trying to build a SQLite database with a singleton pattern in Android, so I can access the same DB through many different activities. I have the code below, but in the `dbInstance = DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());` line, they have flagged an error "Method call expected".

I've searched google and this site, but it seems like this error can be triggered for a variety of reasons, and I wasn't able to figure out what's wrong in my case.

```
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static DatabaseHelper dbInstance = null;

    private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public static DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        synchronized(DatabaseHelper.class) {
            if(dbInstance == null) {
                dbInstance = DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
            }
        }

        return dbInstance;
    }
```

Appreciate all of your help in advance!

Comment: Thank you Mike M. Apologies for overlooking that one

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
dbInstance = new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: Thank you Michel_T. Super helpful